# Calculate coherence for non-gensim topic model

Tags: algorithms, natural-language-processing, python

I've built a topic model, with:

- **Input**: list of tokenized lists
- **Output**: a *m x t* matrix (with each cell indicating the probability of word *i* appearing in topic *k*).
- **Output**: a *k x n* matrix (with each cell indicating the probability of topic *k* in document *j*).

To find the optimal number of topics, I want to calculate the coherence for a model. However, I am only aware of `sklearn`'s `Coherencemodel`, which seems to require a Gensim model as input.

Are there any other packages/implementations that I could use to calculate the coherence of a computed topic model? Or, if it is indeed possible to use the `Coherencemodel` without inputting a LDAmodel, could someone show me how to do that?